# Не могу установить lynx, проблемма с зависимостями (ubuntu 16.04 lts)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

При установке lynx вылетает вот такое сообщение, форумы не помогают,
так же не помогает `apt-get -f install`

```
~# sudo apt-get install lynx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
 lynx : Depends: lynx-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

$ sudo head -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}

```
==> /etc/apt/sources.list <==
# 

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.3)]/ xenial main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.3)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
head: cannot open '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list' for reading: No such file or directory
```

$ lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

$ cat /etc/*release*

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Comment: `Try 'apt-get update'`

Comment: пробовал, не помогло

Comment: что вы пробовали? повторить установку после обновления списка пакетов? тогда приложите к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit]) вывод команды `$ head -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}; lsb_release -a; cat /etc/*release*`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin приложил к тексту дополнительную информацию

Comment: повторяю: `$ head -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}`

Comment: исправил, там в конце ошибка выходит

Comment: я бы рекомендовал закомментировать репозиторий с backport-ами.

Comment: закоментировал репозиторий `deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse`

сделал
`apt-get update`
`apt-get -f install`
`sudo apt-get install lynx` вывод последней команды не поменялся

Comment: значит настало время разбираться с криво собранным пакетом с программой linux.

Comment: спасибо, дальше копать не буду, я программист, наконец-то этим админы займутся) спасибо за помощь)